# TYPO3 get category uid at FLUID template (sys_category)

Tags: templates, typo3, categories, typoscript, fluid

I try to show my category uid or name as a `class="category.uid"` at my FLUID template.

If I try `<f:debug>{data}</f:debug>` I'll see there are an output like: `categories => '1' (1 chars)`

But how can I write the category-uid or -name into my FLUID/HTML, similar like this:

```
<div id="container" class="{data.nav_title}">
<!-- I need the categories --> 
<div id="container" class="{categories.uid}">
```

THanks for your help.

EDIT: some screenshots
The info is in table `sys_category`title, uid, pid ..

[image: sys_category TYPO3]

---

[image: example some categories overall TYPO3]

- `{data}
  [image: {data}]

Comment: What is {categories}? Is it array or ObjectStorage? Is it properly mapped in your Domain Model? Please, provide more info.

Comment: TYPO3 Overall Categories (== System records in table sys_category), see my `edit`  ..screenshot

Comment: I see now. I didn't work with system categories yet, but most probably you should iterate through them via `f:for` ViewHelper, and then you can fetch an _id_

Comment: Ok, thanks. I see, that `<f:debug>data</f:debug>`only get an bool variable (1 or 0). With the `f:for`ViewHelper, I only get the uid, not the title. So that's not enough. I will find another way to get my class into the template. thanks

Comment: I've created a feature request for fluid: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/82010

Answer (score 1):

The same problem is discussed [here](https://fluidtypo3.org/community/irc-logs.html?tx_fluidtypo3org_content[date]=20141112&cHash=35383698cbd0637686aa5a51117d4a99#11:30:26) (see 11:30 - 12:31).

So there is no viewhelper for this. You have to register a ContentController with Flux.

Comment: Writing a custom ViewHelper is a better solution for that task, I thing. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39224703/2564552

Answer (score 1):

I have used a variant of the solution here: [How can I get the category object in Fluid of Typo3 Content Element Pictures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38509145/how-can-i-get-the-category-object-in-fluid-of-typo3-content-element-pictures)

**TypoScript**

```
lib.categories = CONTENT
lib.categories {
    table = sys_category
    select {
        pidInList = root
        selectFields = sys_category.uid
        join = sys_category_record_mm on sys_category_record_mm.uid_local = sys_category.uid
        where.field = recordUid
        where.wrap = sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign=|
    }
    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
        1 = TEXT
        1 {
            field = uid
            stdWrap.noTrimWrap = | cat-||
        }
    }
}
```

**Fluid Template**

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.categories" data="{recordUid: data.uid}" />
```

Comment: This works, but the returned categories are a string and thus must be rendered in TypoScript, not in a for tag within fluid. And also beware that the category entries must on the root element and not a page. And a hint to save time: the resulting SQL query is not shown, when `[SYS][sqlDebug]` is set to 2.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the answer - i do not have enough reputation to comment.

What is `{data}`?

Is it something you get from your controller like?

```
$data = $this->configurationManager->getContentObject()->data;
$this->view->assign('data', $data);
```

If so, then you will need to do some extra processing in your controller since `$data` is an associated array and not an object / model with injection of relations.

Comment: template: I'll get from `<f:debug>{data}</f:debug>`see screenshot above.

Comment: Ok, I see. It´s looks like a page record from the table `pages`. Where do you assign the variable `{data}` to your fluid template?
You have properly done something like this in your template controller `$this->view->assign('data' ,$GLOBALS['TSFE']->page);`

The `categories => '1'` is not a uid of the category but a count of references used internally by TYPO3 CMS. If you try to add another category then you will see this variable changed to `categories => '2'`